# Use LocalStorage in WinForms WebBrowser Control - change event not recieved

Tags: winforms, local-storage

I'm trying to use LocalStorage in HTML code in a web browser control, hosted in a WinForms application. However, the LocalStorage change event is never received. I managed to change the registry and force the control to emulate IE10.

C# code:

```
//Load the html source into the browser control
webBrowser1.Url = new Uri  ("http://localhost/YaronLocalStorageTest/myHtm.htm");
```

Loaded Html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8"/>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=620"/>
          <title>HTML5 Demo: Storage Events</title>

      </head>
      <body>
        <div>
            <p>
              <label for="data">Your test data:</label> 
                           <input type="text" name="data" value="" placeholder="change me" id="data" /> 
            </p>
            <p id="fromEvent">Waiting for data via<code>storage</code>event...
            </p>
       </div>
        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
        var addEvent = (function () {
      if (document.addEventListener) {
        return function (el, type, fn) {
          if (el && el.nodeName || el === window) {
            el.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
          } else if (el && el.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
              addEvent(el[i], type, fn);
            }
          }
        };
      } else {
        return function (el, type, fn) {
          if (el && el.nodeName || el === window) {
            el.attachEvent('on' + type, function () { return     fn.call(el, window.event); });
          } else if (el && el.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
              addEvent(el[i], type, fn);
            }
          }
        };
      }
    })();
</SCRIPT>
<script>
    var dataInput = document.getElementById('data'), output = document
            .getElementById('fromEvent');
    addEvent(window, 'storage', function(event) {
        alert('change notification');
        if (event.key == 'storage-event-test') {
            output.innerHTML = event.newValue;
        }
    });
    addEvent(dataInput, 'keyup', function() {
        localStorage.setItem('storage-event-test', this.value);
    });
</script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: WebBrowser emulates an old version of IE, you'll have to tinker with the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION [registry setting](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version) to get anywhere with this.

Comment: Done that already. I also wrote that I managed to change the registry and force the control to emulate IE10...

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am having the same problem... Thanks

Comment: People claimed it's by design. I have changed the architecture to signalr hub running in win32 service that transfer messages between subscribers. Hope that helps...